# PCRE isn't UTF8 enabled

Tags: linux, pcre

I am attempting to run a regex on my site, and I am getting this response:

> Compilation failed: support for \P,
>   \p, and \X has not been compiled at
>   offset 1

After googling for a bit, I've found that apparently my PCRE on my server is not UTF8 enabled, and is therefore causing problems. When I ssh with pcretest -C I get

```
PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

When I do yum update pcre it tells me that there isn't anything to update.

People are telling me that I can turn on UTF-8 support...help?

I am a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this website.

http://gaarai.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/

It discusses your problem and a solution.

Hope that helps.

David